# matching two object by partial match javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have these 2 objects, where I want to alter the value of a 2nd object by checking the value of the 1st object. But I'm stuck, I've prepared a sample below

```
const inputs = {
  "firstname": "james",
  "lastname": ""
}

const errors = {
  firstname_error: false,
  firstname_error_msg: "first name is invalid",

  lastname_error: false, //make this true because inputs.lastname is false / empty string
  lastname_error_msg: "last name is invalid",

}

Object.entries(inputs).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if(!value) {
    //how to make errors.lastname_error to true if inputs.lastname is false empty string?
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`Square Bracket Notation`** to assign the value.

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the [**square bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). This notation is also very useful when property names are to be dynamically determined (when the property name is not determined until runtime).

Concatenate `_error` to they key which will target required key in `error` object.

```js
const inputs = {
  "firstname": "james",
  "lastname": ""
}

const errors = {
  firstname_error: false,
  firstname_error_msg: "first name is invalid",
  lastname_error: false,
  lastname_error_msg: "last name is invalid",

}

Object.entries(inputs).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (!value) {
    errors[`${key}_error`] = true;
  }
});
console.log(errors);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Lodash library, refer to [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) and [intersection](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#intersection) functions

Answer (score 0):

I get the key value of `inputs` and in a for cycle i check if exist the relative key with "_error" in `errors` object and the value ok `inputs[key]` is not empty.

I use this code and work:

```
const inputs = {
  "firstname": "james",
  "lastname": ""
}

const errors = {
  firstname_error: false,
  firstname_error_msg: "first name is invalid",

  lastname_error: false, //make this true because inputs.lastname is false / empty string
  lastname_error_msg: "last name is invalid",

}


for (const key in inputs) {
    if (errors.hasOwnProperty(`${key}_error`) && !inputs[key]) {
        errors[`${key}_error`] = true; 
  }
}
```